# How to hide the label inside my input?

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins, input, label

I want the labels to reappear if the user deletes their value from the input fields anybody mind using fiddle to give me a hand.
    [My fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/sdavadi/QqDLR/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/QqDLR/2/

```
blur: function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 0) {
        label.hide();
    } else { 
        cssoptwo = {'zoom': '1','filter': 'alpha(opacity=100)','opacity': '1'};
        label.css(cssoptwo).fadeIn();

    }
}
```

Comment: you're welcome :) and I'd suggest to use `keydown` to hide the label instead of `keyup` - if you press any key and hold it down the input is filled with text, but the label is still there ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you are calling 'fadeOut()' and 'hide()' functions, after that calls your label has declaration 'display:none;'. To re-show your label you have to call functions like fadeIn(), or show(), or change this declaration for 'display:block;' manually like I did [here in your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tonybo/QqDLR/5/)